Turborepo symlink to external application
I'd like to integrate a pre-existing JS app with a pre-existing Turborepo monorepo.
I have a turbo repo set up in a directory that exists inside a larger repository. It looks something like this...
- my-repo
  - my-turbo-repo
    - packages
      - ui
    - apps
      - my-first-app
      - my-second-app
  - my-legacy-js-app

I'd like to configure my-legacy-js-app to be an app in my-turbo-repo, but I'd prefer not to move the my-legacy-js-app directory.
I thought I might be able to simply symlink to my-legacy-js-app from inside my-turbo-repo/apps, something like the following...
- my-repo
  - my-turbo-repo
    - packages
      - ui
    - apps
      - my-first-app
      - my-second-app
      - my-symlink-app -> my-legacy-js-app
  - my-legacy-js-app

But with this ^ setup, turbo commands, such as turbo dev, executed from my-turbo-repo do not detect my-legacy-js-app linked via my-symlink-app.  (it does detect my-first-app and my-second-app, just not my-symlink-app)
Another thing I was hoping to achieve with this strategy was the ability to consume internal packages (my-turbo-repo/packages), e.g. "@my-repo/ui": "*", from within my-legacy-js-app.  But this results in a 404 error, e.g. when I run npm install from within my-turbo-repo/apps/my-symlink-app (or from my-legacy-js-app).
Maybe such a configuration is simply not possible with Turborepo.  Or maybe I'm just missing something...?
